# How to debug apex class in Sublime Text 3

Tags: debugging, salesforce, sublimetext3, breakpoints, apex-code

I'm using Sublime Text 3 for salesforce project (apex class, visual force page) and I want to debugging its (NOT System.debug(''); but debug with breakpoints). I downloaded Web Inspector Tool but I didn't sure is right tool for debugging salesforce app. Because I configured swi.sublime-settings and I receive this error in console:

```
[WinError 193] %1 non è un'applicazione di Win32 valida
```

Translation:

```
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Can you help me please?
Do you know another tool for debugging apex code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no ability to debug Apex code as you are able to do it with Java or C# code (use breakpoints, go through stack, etc). You can only analyze logs.